# sed strange behaviour when executed inside grave accent - `

Tags: linux, bash, sed, sh

For some reason I need to escape forward slash inside some string

```
# echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's/[/]/\\\//g'
http:\/\/google.com
```

But when I try to execute the same inside `` it shows me:

```
# somevar=`echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's/[/]/\\\//g'`
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
```

My sed's version:

```
# rpm -q sed
sed-4.1.5-8.el5
```

Comment: I find it curious that you need to escape slashes. Probably your problem could be solved more elegantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the inside the backticks (aka backquotes, grave accents), `\\` is replaced with `\` before the command is parsed.

From the bash manpage:

> When the old-style backquote form of substitution is used, backslash retains its literal meaning except when followed by $, `, or
>   \.  The first backquote not preceded by a backslash terminates the 
>   command  sub‐
>      stitution.  When using the $(command) form, all characters between the parentheses make up the command; none are treated
>   specially.

Just use `$(...)` instead of backticks, unless you really need pre-posix `sh` compatibility

```
somevar=$(echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's/[/]/\\\//g')
```

I'd also recommend using a regex delimiter other than `/` to make this easier, e.g.

```
somevar=$(echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's|/|\\/|g')
```

Comment: `$(...)` is POSIX shell; it's older pre-POSIX shells that one might need to worry about.  But in any case it's not related to the problem; the *first* example is the weird one, `sed` doesn't usually allow `[]` to escape its regex delimiter.

Comment: @geekosaur thanks, I did not know that. It always amazes me how so many people *still* use backticks despite how long `$(...)` has been available.

Answer (score 0):

Use a different delimiter and you'll be fine. I can't tell you why it works from the command line, but just fix it so it works everywhere.

```
somevar=`echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's%[/]%\\/%g'`
```

Comment: it's not working, $somevar ends up with `http://google.com`, you still have to escape the string again like i said in my answer

Comment: No, you just have to quote it properly when using it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the string once again.

```
$ echo `echo \x`  # tilde is executing "echo x"
x
$ echo `echo \\x`   # tilde is executing "echo \x"
x
$ echo `echo \\\x`   # tilde is executing "echo \\x"
\x
```

In your case you should add 2 extra slashes

```
$ echo `echo "http://google.com" | sed -e 's/[/]/\\\\\//g'`
http:\/\/google.com
```

Comment: Or add proper quoting. As a general comment, using `echo` to see the actual value if a variable isn't recommended, but at a minimum, you have to use proper quoting (i.e. double quotes).

Comment: It was an example to show why his code didn't work, i'd have done it exactly as je4d did in his second example. He asked about the strange behavior, not how to do it correctly.